# flutter background image flexible

Tags: android, flutter, flexible-type

I try to put a background image on a flexible but I can't, I manage to put a background color can you help me thank you in advance

```
 Flexible(

        child: prodcuts(counterToGetCategory,widget.loginUserId,widget.attributeMap),

      ),
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for.

```
 Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Flexible(
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.red,
                image: DecorationImage(
                  image: Image.asset('assets/images/logo.png').image,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

Let me know if it is not.

Comment: can you please explain better what it is you want then because this does work for what I thought you wanted sorry I must have misunderstood you

Answer (score 0):

I put the end of the color, the color works but I would prefer to put an image

```
 backgroundColor: Colors.purple,

  body:

  Column(

    children: <Widget>[


      //3shan l swr ele btt8yer fo2
       Container(

        height: 150.0,
        child: Carousel(
          boxFit: BoxFit.cover,
          images: [
            AssetImage('images/pic1.jpeg'),
            AssetImage('images/pic2.jpeg'),
            AssetImage('images/pic3.jpeg'),
            AssetImage('images/pic4.jpeg'),
            AssetImage('images/pic5.jpeg'),
            AssetImage('images/pic6.jpeg'),
          ],
          autoplay: true,
          animationCurve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
          animationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
          dotSize: 4.0,
          indicatorBgPadding: 3.0,
          dotIncreasedColor: Colors.black,
        ),
      ),
      Divider(color: Colors.black ),
      Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        child: Container(

          alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
          child: Text(
            'Products',
            style:
            TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      //grid view
      // l list ele bt3rd l 7gat

      Flexible(


        child: prodcuts(

            counterToGetCategory,widget.loginUserId,widget.attributeMap

        ),

      ),

    ],
  ),
);
```

}